# Can uneven surface on a violin impact the sound quality?

Tags: violin

I saw some violins whose back surfaces are uneven, as seen from the light reflecting off the surface. Would this impact the violin acoustically?

See the picture below for an illustration of the uneven surface. All images are from the Internet.
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to add more description or a picture. I imagine that you're describing the "quilted" pattern in the grain of the maple (like in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_maple#/media/File:Italian_Violin_by_Ansaldo_Poggi,_Bologna,_Stradivari_Model,_Back.jpg)), but you could also be saying something about the shape or fit of various parts of the back. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AndyBonner I just added a picture. As shown in the picture, I am not talking about the flame.

Comment: As a physicist I'd say No. E.g. waevlength in air is ~10 cm at 30 kHz, and some multiples shorter in wood (higher c). So any uneveness on this scale (which is almost "infinite" below 30 kHz) below this range will give hardly any effect. // Back in air, propagation, your hot spots of uneveness had to be a few wavelength's apart to cause >additional< wave effects. So, No again. // So it boils down to esthetics, not sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wood is an organic material that does not grow isotropically and with equal density and material characteristics in each direction.  Master instruments are not CNC-machined into the final shape but are worked upon by hand respecting the grain and structure of te material to achieve a balance of stability, tension, form, pliability and sound emission.  That makes the instruments lighter than machined instruments (which need to end up substantially thicker since they cannot take into account the wood's structure in the same way a hand-crafted instrument does).

Because of the non-uniformness of the building material, a perfectly shaped (namely milled) instrument is less likely to produce a great quality of sound than an instrument that takes into account the individual wood piece's structure.

In the end, it is the sound that counts, and whether the instrument has the necessary overall stability and pliability to stay in its shape while producing a great sound quality.

In short: if there is well-considered reason and judgment and material skill involved with deviations from a perfect geometric shape, this can actually be an advantage.  Of course, if the body is indeed isotropic, or predictably anisotropic like plexiglass or carbon fibre, it is to be expected that the best feasible result may indeed be in perfect geometric shape.

But so far, wood still carries the day.

Answer (score 1):

[This news story](https://english.kyodonews.net/news/2022/06/97961b02be25-japanese-owned-stradivarius-violin-sells-for-15-million-at-auction.html) has a photo of a Stradivarius violin that seems to have the same surface variations. If this looks like the same "unevenness" to you, then I think we can be confident that it does not have a negative effect on tone.

[image]

Comment: But does it have a positive effect on tone?